# Use pandas.shift() within a group

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe with panel data, let's say it's time series for 100 different objects:

```
object  period  value 
1       1       24
1       2       67
...
1       1000    56
2       1       59
2       2       46
...
2       1000    64
3       1       54
...
100     1       451
100     2       153
...
100     1000    21
```

I want to add a new column `prev_value` that will store previous `value` for each object:

```
object  period  value  prev_value
1       1       24     nan
1       2       67     24
...
1       99      445    1243
1       1000    56     445
2       1       59     nan
2       2       46     59
...
2       1000    64     784
3       1       54     nan
...
100     1       451    nan
100     2       153    451
...
100     1000    21     1121
```

Can I use `.shift()` and `.groupby()` somehow to do that?

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Pandas' grouped objects have a [`groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html) method, which will shift a specified column in each group *n* `periods`, just like the regular dataframe's `shift` method:

```
df['prev_value'] = df.groupby('object')['value'].shift()
```

For the following example dataframe:

```
print(df)

     object  period  value
0       1       1     24
1       1       2     67
2       1       4     89
3       2       4      5
4       2      23     23
```

The result would be:

```
     object  period  value  prev_value
0       1       1     24         NaN
1       1       2     67        24.0
2       1       4     89        67.0
3       2       4      5         NaN
4       2      23     23         5.0
```

Comment: Just beware, it is safer to sort dataframe beforehand: 

`df.sort_values(by=['period']).groupby('object')['value'].shift()`

Answer (score 20):

IFF your DataFrame is already sorted by the grouping keys you can use a single `shift` on the entire DataFrame and  `where` to `NaN` the rows that overflow into the next group. For larger DataFrames with many groups this can be a bit faster.

```
df['prev_value'] = df['value'].shift().where(df.object.eq(df.object.shift()))

   object  period  value  prev_value
0       1       1     24         NaN
1       1       2     67        24.0
2       1       4     89        67.0
3       2       4      5         NaN
4       2      23     23         5.0
```

---

Some performance related timings:

```
import perfplot
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda N: pd.DataFrame({'object': np.repeat(range(N), 5), 
                                  'value': np.random.randint(1, 1000, 5*N)}), 
    kernels=[
        lambda df: df.groupby('object')['value'].shift(),
        lambda df: df['value'].shift().where(df.object.eq(df.object.shift())),
    ],
    labels=["GroupBy", "Where"],
    n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(1, 22)],
    equality_check=lambda x,y: np.allclose(x, y, equal_nan=True),
    xlabel="# of Groups"
)
```

[image]

Comment: happy to learn about perfplot as well!