# How to subtract rows of a Pandas dataframe based upon some conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am performing analysis on [this](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/sudalairajkumar/covid19-in-india) dataset.

After using the code below, I am left with the cleaned version of the data.

```
covid_df.drop(columns = ["Sno", "Time"], inplace = True)
```

```
covid_df["State/UnionTerritory"] = covid_df["State/UnionTerritory"].replace({
    "Bihar****": "Bihar",
    "Maharashtra***": "Maharashtra", 
    "Madhya Pradesh***": "Madhya Pradesh", 
    "Karanataka": "Karnataka",
    "Telangana": "Telengana",
    "Himanchal Pradesh": "Himachal Pradesh",
    "Dadra and Nagar Haveli": "Dadra and Nagar Haveli and Daman and Diu",
    "Daman & Diu": "Dadra and Nagar Haveli and Daman and Diu"
    })

invalid_states = ["Cases being reassigned to states", "Unassigned"]

for invalid_state in invalid_states:
  invalid_state_index = covid_df.loc[covid_df["State/UnionTerritory"] == invalid_state, :].index
  covid_df.drop(index = invalid_state_index, inplace = True)
```

```
covid_df = covid_df.groupby(["State/UnionTerritory", "Date"], as_index = False).sum()
```

```
covid_df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(covid_df["Date"])
covid_df.sort_values(by = ["State/UnionTerritory", "Date"], inplace = True)
```

This cleaned data has the cumulative cases for each **State/UnionTerritory** for each **Date**. How can I extract the daily new cases for each **State/UnionTerritory**?

This is what I have tried:

```
daily_cases_data = [list(covid_df.iloc[0, 2:])]

for index in range(1, covid_df.shape[0]):
  previous_row = covid_df.iloc[index - 1, :]
  current_row = covid_df.iloc[index, :]

  if previous_row["State/UnionTerritory"] == current_row["State/UnionTerritory"]:
    daily_cases_data.append(list(current_row[2:] - previous_row[2:]))
  else:
    daily_cases_data.append(list(current_row[2:]))
```

Is there a more efficient way for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited answer: use groupby.shift**
As seen here: [Use pandas.shift() within a group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53335567/use-pandas-shift-within-a-group)

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'state': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c'],
        'cumul': [1, 2, 5, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 9]
    }
)
df['quantity'] = df['cumul'] - df.groupby('state')['cumul'].shift()
```

**Previous answer:**

You could use `shift`.
For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'cumul': [0, 2, 3, 5, 7]})
df['quantity'] = df - df.shift(1)
```

`quantity` will be:

```
   quantity
0    NaN
1    2.0
2    1.0
3    2.0
4    2.0
```

You can then `fillna` or just change the zeroth value in quantity for the zeroth value in cumul.

Edit: prepare the dataframe by applying your conditions first :-)

Comment: The problem with this method is that it would subtract each previous row from the current one. What I want is to subtract the previous row from the current one only when both have the same **State/UnionTerritory** value.

Comment: @IshanShishodiya I edited the answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

It feels weird to answer my own question, but this did the job for me

```
grouped_df = covid_df.groupby("State/UnionTerritory")
daily_cases_df = pd.DataFrame()

for state in covid_df["State/UnionTerritory"].unique():
  group = grouped_df.get_group(state)
  cases_group = group.iloc[:, 2:] - group.shift(1).iloc[:, 2:]
  cases_group.iloc[0, :] = group.iloc[0, 2:]
  group = pd.concat([group.iloc[:, :2], cases_group], axis = 1)
  
  daily_cases_df = pd.concat([daily_cases_df, group])
```