# polars equivalent to pandas groupby shift()

Tags: python-polars

Is there an equivalent way to to df.groupby().shift in polars? [Use pandas.shift() within a group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53335567/use-pandas-shift-within-a-group)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the [`over`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.Expr.over.html) expression to accomplish this in Polars.  Using the example from the link...

```py
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({
    'object': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
    'period': [1, 2, 4, 4, 23],
    'value': [24, 67, 89, 5, 23],
})

df.with_column(
    pl.col('value').shift().over('object').alias('prev_value')
)
```

```
shape: (5, 4)
┌────────┬────────┬───────┬────────────┐
│ object ┆ period ┆ value ┆ prev_value │
│ ---    ┆ ---    ┆ ---   ┆ ---        │
│ i64    ┆ i64    ┆ i64   ┆ i64        │
╞════════╪════════╪═══════╪════════════╡
│ 1      ┆ 1      ┆ 24    ┆ null       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1      ┆ 2      ┆ 67    ┆ 24         │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1      ┆ 4      ┆ 89    ┆ 67         │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2      ┆ 4      ┆ 5     ┆ null       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2      ┆ 23     ┆ 23    ┆ 5          │
└────────┴────────┴───────┴────────────┘
```

To perform this on more than one column, you can specify the columns in the `pl.col` expression, and then use a prefix/suffix to name the new columns.  For example:

```py
df.with_columns(
    pl.col(['period', 'value']).shift().over('object').prefix("prev_")
)
```

```
shape: (5, 5)
┌────────┬────────┬───────┬─────────────┬────────────┐
│ object ┆ period ┆ value ┆ prev_period ┆ prev_value │
│ ---    ┆ ---    ┆ ---   ┆ ---         ┆ ---        │
│ i64    ┆ i64    ┆ i64   ┆ i64         ┆ i64        │
╞════════╪════════╪═══════╪═════════════╪════════════╡
│ 1      ┆ 1      ┆ 24    ┆ null        ┆ null       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1      ┆ 2      ┆ 67    ┆ 1           ┆ 24         │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1      ┆ 4      ┆ 89    ┆ 2           ┆ 67         │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2      ┆ 4      ┆ 5     ┆ null        ┆ null       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2      ┆ 23     ┆ 23    ┆ 4           ┆ 5          │
└────────┴────────┴───────┴─────────────┴────────────┘
```

##### Using multiple values with `over`

Let's use this data.

```py
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "id": [1] * 5 + [2] * 5,
        "date": ["2020-01-01", "2020-01-01", "2020-02-01", "2020-02-01", "2020-02-01"] * 2,
        "value1": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
        "value2": [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100],
    }
).with_column(pl.col('date').str.strptime(pl.Date))
df
```

```
shape: (10, 4)
┌─────┬────────────┬────────┬────────┐
│ id  ┆ date       ┆ value1 ┆ value2 │
│ --- ┆ ---        ┆ ---    ┆ ---    │
│ i64 ┆ date       ┆ i64    ┆ i64    │
╞═════╪════════════╪════════╪════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 2020-01-01 ┆ 1      ┆ 10     │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1   ┆ 2020-01-01 ┆ 2      ┆ 20     │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1   ┆ 2020-02-01 ┆ 3      ┆ 30     │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1   ┆ 2020-02-01 ┆ 4      ┆ 40     │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1   ┆ 2020-02-01 ┆ 5      ┆ 50     │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ 2020-01-01 ┆ 6      ┆ 60     │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ 2020-01-01 ┆ 7      ┆ 70     │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ 2020-02-01 ┆ 8      ┆ 80     │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ 2020-02-01 ┆ 9      ┆ 90     │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ 2020-02-01 ┆ 10     ┆ 100    │
└─────┴────────────┴────────┴────────┘
```

We can place a list of our grouping variables in the `over` expression (as well as a list in our `pl.col` expression).  Polars will run them all in parallel.

```py
df.with_columns([
    pl.col(["value1", "value2"]).shift().over(['id','date']).prefix("prev_"),
    pl.col(["value1", "value2"]).diff().over(['id','date']).suffix("_diff"),
])
```

```
shape: (10, 8)
┌─────┬────────────┬────────┬────────┬─────────────┬─────────────┬─────────────┬─────────────┐
│ id  ┆ date       ┆ value1 ┆ value2 ┆ prev_value1 ┆ prev_value2 ┆ value1_diff ┆ value2_diff │
│ --- ┆ ---        ┆ ---    ┆ ---    ┆ ---         ┆ ---         ┆ ---         ┆ ---         │
│ i64 ┆ date       ┆ i64    ┆ i64    ┆ i64         ┆ i64         ┆ i64         ┆ i64         │
╞═════╪════════════╪════════╪════════╪═════════════╪═════════════╪═════════════╪═════════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 2020-01-01 ┆ 1      ┆ 10     ┆ null        ┆ null        ┆ null        ┆ null        │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1   ┆ 2020-01-01 ┆ 2      ┆ 20     ┆ 1           ┆ 10          ┆ 1           ┆ 10          │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1   ┆ 2020-02-01 ┆ 3      ┆ 30     ┆ null        ┆ null        ┆ null        ┆ null        │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1   ┆ 2020-02-01 ┆ 4      ┆ 40     ┆ 3           ┆ 30          ┆ 1           ┆ 10          │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1   ┆ 2020-02-01 ┆ 5      ┆ 50     ┆ 4           ┆ 40          ┆ 1           ┆ 10          │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ 2020-01-01 ┆ 6      ┆ 60     ┆ null        ┆ null        ┆ null        ┆ null        │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ 2020-01-01 ┆ 7      ┆ 70     ┆ 6           ┆ 60          ┆ 1           ┆ 10          │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ 2020-02-01 ┆ 8      ┆ 80     ┆ null        ┆ null        ┆ null        ┆ null        │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ 2020-02-01 ┆ 9      ┆ 90     ┆ 8           ┆ 80          ┆ 1           ┆ 10          │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ 2020-02-01 ┆ 10     ┆ 100    ┆ 9           ┆ 90          ┆ 1           ┆ 10          │
└─────┴────────────┴────────┴────────┴─────────────┴─────────────┴─────────────┴─────────────┘
```

Comment: Does it matter for performance for order?  can i do df.with_columns( with over a few times)

Comment: You can do more than one expression with `over` in a `with_columns` context.  I'll edit my answer to show an easy way.

Comment: Also How do you do two columns?  I have in my data: date, id

Comment: I would do stuff like groupby(["date", "id"]).diff() and groupby(["date", "id"]).shift()

Comment: Sure, let me add that to my answer...

Comment: fantastic, I am testing a process in polars and wasn't sure on a few of these

Comment: why does output contains nulls? sensor 1 with value1=3 has prev_value1=null, but actually it's 2...

Comment: ok, since it's .over(['id','date']) but how does polars know how to preserve sorting if I remove date from over condition?