# Python Pandas - Shift grouped values to next date

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I'm trying to build a model for timeseries analysis and I want to create some features which contain values of previous rows.

I have a dataset as follows:

| item_id | shop_id | items_sold | date_block_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 5 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | 10 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 7 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 8 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 5 | 1 |

And I want to add a column containing the amount of items sold for each item/shop combination, from the previous date block. So something like:

| item_id | shop_id | items_sold | date_block_id | lag1_items_sold |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 5 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | 10 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 7 | 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 2 | 8 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 5 | 1 | 0 |

I think what makes this hard is the fact that if no sale is made within a date block, no entry of that item/shop combination is present in the table. I have tried al sorts of combinations of grouping and shifting, but I can't seem to get the result I want.

Answer (score 0):

Look at `df.shift` combined with group by. Docs for shift [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html).

Older answer with code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53335567/use-pandas-shift-within-a-group). Try searching through SO next time and you might find the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
df["lag1_items_sold"] = (
    df.groupby(["item_id", "shop_id"])["items_sold"].shift().fillna(0)
)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   item_id  shop_id  items_sold  date_block_id  lag1_items_sold
0        1        1           5              0              0.0
1        1        2          10              0              0.0
2        1        1           7              1              5.0
3        2        2           8              1              0.0
4        2        1           5              1              0.0
```